# <Connect /> re-renders onSubscriptionMsg, but not with new data

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I have a really simple component using `Connect` from `aws-amplify-react`

```
const EmployeeExpensesTable = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => { Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user => setUser(user)) }, [])
  console.log(user)

  if(!user) { return null }

  return (
    <Connect

      query={graphqlOperation(queries.listTransactions, { owner: user.username })}

      subscription={graphqlOperation(subscriptions.onCreateTransaction, { owner: user.username })}

      onSubscriptionMsg={(prev, { onCreateTransaction }) => {
        console.log('oncreatetransaction:', onCreateTransaction)
        console.log('prev', prev)
        return onCreateTransaction
      }}

    >
      {
        ({ data: { listTransactions }, loading, errors }) => {

          console.log('transactions', listTransactions)

          if (errors.length) return (<h3>Error</h3>)

          if (loading || !listTransactions) return (<p>loading...</p>)

          return (<core.components.Table data={listTransactions.items} />)
        }
      }
    </Connect>
  )
}

export default EmployeeExpensesTable
```

I have an external ETL process that adds transactions to the DynamoDB table.  The subscription is firing and my `oncreatetransaction` message is being displayed with the new data, and the `Connect` component re-renders, but it renders using it's original data, not the new data.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that `onSubscriptionMsg` is like the reducer for the `Connect` component's state.  You are given the previous value and the new value to the function and you need to return the new state.

```
onSubscriptionMsg={(prev, data) => ({
        listTransactions: {
          items: [...prev.listTransactions.items.slice(-9), data.onCreateTransaction ]
        }
      })
```

The above works great for me.  The `.slice(-9)` is because I only care about the last 10 rows that were added.